# Forcing a sql script to be executed with result to text in SSMS

Tags: sql, ssms

I usually need to send the result of my queries to "Grid" when using SSMS but I have a specific script the result of which i need to send "to text". Is there a way to script this at the beginning of my .sql file?
I imagine it is something that only SSMS could understand and it won't be a generic sql statement

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might find this Reddit thread helpful in your case:https://www.reddit.com/r/SQLServer/comments/1vrlx3/i_want_to_turn_on_text_output_via_sql_command/

Basically, if you have SQLCMD mode turned on, run the following to print to text:

```
:OUT STDOUT 
SELECT * FROM TABLE
```

To issue a warning if the script is executed without SQLCMD mode turned on, you can use the check below:

```
SET NOEXEC OFF; -- previous execution may have toggled it
:setvar IsSqlCmdEnabled "True"
GO
IF ('$(IsSqlCmdEnabled)' = '$' + '(IsSqlCmdEnabled)')
BEGIN
  PRINT('Use SqlCmd-mode!!');
  SET NOEXEC ON;
  -- RAISERROR ('This script must be run in SQLCMD mode.', 20, 1) WITH LOG
END
ELSE
BEGIN
  PRINT('Using SqlCmd-mode')
  -- insert the code you really want to execute:
  -- ...
END
SET NOEXEC OFF; -- do not disable next execution in this session
```

Comment: it seems to me that if sqlcmd mode is off i can't even use the first setvar to tell me that it is turned off... it just doesnt compile. Beside this, the answer was very useful.